# Can CSS3 transition font size?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

How can one make the font size grow bigger on mouse over? Color transitions work fine over time, but the font size switches immediately for some reason.

Sample code:

```
body p {
     font-size: 12px;
     color: #0F9;
     transition:font-size 12s;
     -moz-transition:font-size 12s; /* Firefox 4 */
     -webkit-transition:font-size 12s; /* Safari and Chrome */
     -o-transition:font-size 12s;
     transition:color 12s;
     -moz-transition:color 12s; /* Firefox 4 */
     -webkit-transition:color 12s; /* Safari and Chrome */
     -o-transition:color 12s;
}

 p:hover {
      font-size: 40px;
      color:#FC0;
 }
```

Answer (score 123, accepted):

> The color transitions fine over time, but the font switches
>   immediately for some dagnabbit reason.

Your `font-size` transition is being overwritten by your `color` transition.

```
transition: font-size 12s; /* transition is set to 'font-size 12s' */
transition: color 12s;     /* transition is set to 'color 12s' !! */
```

Instead, you must combine them all into one declaration:

```
transition: color 12s, font-size 12s;
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/6HCRs/

```
-webkit-transition: color 12s, font-size 12s;
   -moz-transition: color 12s, font-size 12s;
     -o-transition: color 12s, font-size 12s;
        transition: color 12s, font-size 12s;
```

(Or, just use the `all` keyword: `transition: all 12s;` - http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/6HCRs/1/).

Comment: +one for using the word 'dagnabbit' in response to op's 'what in tarnation' question :P #LanguageStyleMatching

Comment: That was OPs phasing, someone edited it out of his question for whatever reason.

Comment: I would argue not to use the `all` keyword for transition for performance reasons. It can make your page horrendously slow. Opt in for the more verbose syntax: 
`transition: color 12s, font-size 12s;`

Comment: is there a way to do the same effect but with the *background-color* and *background-clip* properties? I'm trying to do this :) and would appreciate if there's already a solution for this.

Comment: @LeonardoMaffei: I recommend asking a new question if you can't find an answer. Be sure to include your code, a demo, and a good explanation of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 75):

Try set transition for all properties:

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

it is works as well.

**OR** 
just font: `transition: font 0.3s ease`.

Comment: wrong answer, it works, but font-size isn't a "subproperty" of font. font property doesn't exists, it's a shorthand property

Answer (score 31):

Transitions for `font-size` seem to step by pixel and thus aren't smooth.

If it's just one line, you might be able to use `transform: scale(.8)`. Scale down and not up so you don't lose quality. You will likely also need to use `transform-origin: 0 0` or a different value depending on your text alignment.

```css
#size ,#transform{
  height: 80px;
  position:absolute;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

#size {
  animation-name: size;
}

@keyframes size {
  from {
    font-size:10px;
    left:155px;
    top:40px;
  }

  to {
    font-size:80px;
    top:0;
    left:30px;
  }
}

#transform {
  animation-name: transform;
  transform-origin: center middle;
  font-size:80px;
  top:80px;
}

@keyframes transform {
  from {
    transform:scale(.1);
  }
  to {
    transform:scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id=size>Font-size</div>
<div id=transform>Transform</div>
```

Comment: This is a really good tip! Was facing jerky animations on font-size on mobile, particularly Android, while it was all fine on desktop. Relying on `transform: scale()` in place of `font-size` fixed it. It's now smooth on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fecWK/)

An alternative would be that you can also use a framework such as [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) to do this easily for you:

**Javascript:**

```
$("p").hover( function () {
    //On hover in
    $("p").transition({ 'color': '#FC0', 'font-size': '40px' }, 1000);    
}, function () {
    //On hover out
    $("p").transition({ 'color': '#0F9', 'font-size': '12px' }, 1000);
});
```

**CSS:**

```
p 
{

font-size: 12px;
color: #0F9;

}
```

Comment: The question doesn't even reference javascript.