# h1 fade effect using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've googled various examples but I cant seem to get the desired effect to work 
On my home page I have a h1 heading.

I'm trying to create a fade effect with JQuery . When the page loads, I would like the h1 heading to fade in slowly (maybe even go from a small font to large)

Can anyone help with the code. Apologies, I've just stated out?

Many thanks,
P

Answer (score 3):

Look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/gg9rbL7o/1/)
I think it's a lot smoother if you fadein and chenge the font size at the same time.

Also , see the 1000 at the bottom part of the code? That's the animation time, you can change that for faster or slower performance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h1").animate({ 
        'font-size' : '40px',
        'opacity': '1'
    },1000);
});
```

Comment: Additionally & optionally, you may add a 2nd parameter (number) to .animate(), which would specify the duration/speed of animation in milliseconds $("h1").animate({ 
        'font-size' : '40px',
        'opacity': '1'
    },10000);

Comment: @playmaker Well, I already have set the duration/speed of the animation...I even explained that : "Also , see the 1000 at the bottom part of the code? That's the animation time, you can change that for faster or slower performance."

Comment: Oh, my bad. Missed seeing it.

Comment: @playmaker it's ok :D

Answer (score 2):

jQuery.fadein() animation can be choppy sometimes while the dom loads (or if you are downloading/rendering a data payload.) Might have gotten better over the years but hey... here is the $-free solution:

```
h1 {
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
       -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox < 16 */
        -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
         -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
            animation: fadein 2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; } }
@-moz-keyframes fadein { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; } }
@-ms-keyframes fadein { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; } }
@-o-keyframes fadein { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; } }
@keyframes fadein { from { opacity: 0; } to { opacity: 1; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

See output below or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wxgce21r/)

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("h1").fadeIn("slow").animate({ fontSize : '40px' });
    
    })
```

```css
      h1{display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Comment: Hey, your code is good but I think you didn't check the snippet, it's not running :)

Comment: Not working for me as well. Double ';' in first bit would be the issue I assume.

Comment: Yes, I am clicking the button but it's not working :)) and it should cause your code is right

Comment: strane @Alin and playmaker for making me know i was just doing it on many posts, may be it wont be working there as well. as it is working fine here strange

Comment: getting this error in console: "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at "http://stacksnippets.net" from accessing a frame at "null".  Both frames are sandboxed and lack the "allow-same-origin" flag."

Comment: it may be other error, thats really a problem for me.

Comment: Code works in jsfiddle though: http://jsfiddle.net/wxgce21r/ - add that instead of snippet..

Comment: Welcome :) - really strange issue though.

Comment: how can i report this? can you please check my answer here works or not ? "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463232/next-and-previous-in-jquery-array/27463298#27463298"

Comment: @A.B I've checked it over there and it's working..it's a really strange bug.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you'd want `<h1>` shown by default, in case the end user doesn't have Javascript installed, but hidden by Javascript which is called between your `<head></head>` tags, so that it's hidden before the page loads. Put the rest of the Javascript right before your `</body>` tag, so it loads lastly.

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script src="doFirst.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class='title'>My Title</h1>
    <!-- page content -->
    <script src="doLast.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### doFirst.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h1.title").hide();
});
```

Use the [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function to hide the element.

### doLast.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h1.title").fadeIn(3000);
});
```

Use the [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadein/) function to control the fade. The number represents the fade speed in milliseconds.

See a live [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8mzjjvw/).

## Update

You can also do this with CSS3.

[See how to fade in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679567/using-css-for-fade-in-effect-on-page-load).

[See how to grow font in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311116/can-css3-transition-font-size-what-in-tarnation-am-i-doing-wrong).